# Show two projects in one UML diagram

Tags: java, dependencies, uml

I have an enum that has two dependencies. These two are in different projects (Im coding in Java). I want to show this dependency ina UML diagram but how can I show what projects these classes are from? (I know for packages you can put it like this: Package :: pkgName).
Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What tool are you using?

In Rational Rose, if you this structure:

```
Folder1
 |___Class1
Folder2
 |___ClassDiagramX
```

and the ClassDiagramX shows Class1 then you'll see a small "stereotype" like note indicating "from Folder1" in the box representing Class1.

That should be sufficient.

There are other options using fancy-colorful-notes, but I don't care so much for them.

--edit--
Without knowing the tool I can't really say what you can and can not do. From UML pov, I don't know of any defined convention, so whatever conveys what you wan to can be used. Class diagram is a representation and does not affect the meta-data of the class (e.g. which project it belongs to). So as long as the "class" is in the correct package, it's doesn't matter how it's "shown" in the class diagram.

E.g. in the class-diagram you can put up 2 big squares in the background showing / grouping classes from each project and dependency arrows running across these groups.

OR

"add the line" if that's possible in your tool.

Comment: Im using some free tool. My issue is how to display it. I think Uml has standards like if its a class is goes in that kind of square...so how do I add the project name. Can I just put it on the line before the class name in that box?

Comment: Comment became too big so added to answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse and java then you have a feature which allow to join two different projects. I mean open the package explorer and click on the project name then select join, or merge with I don't really remember the exact title of the menu but it is easy to find.

Once your both projects have been joined your can create a class diagram and just drag drop inside the same diagram two classifiers coming from different projects.

Answer (score 0):

Project in the sense of "a set of planned activities and deliverables, with common goal" can not be reasonably encoded in UML.

Project in the sense of "a set of related files and metadata that allows an IDE to compile and run a program" is out of scope for UML, as this is a development environment artifact and not application design artifact.

For example, you can decide to use multiple projects for each module of your app or a single project for all modules. This will not change your design, only the instructions for the IDE - it's even possible that different team members have different project configurations, especially if some use Eclipse, others IntelliJ IDEA and some EMACS.

On the other hand, if you still want to denote logical sets of classes, you do have options - the formal way would be to use tagged values. Alternatively, I often use colors (for example, green for public API, yellow for extension points/SPI and red for implementation classes; or blue for low-latency multicast component, green for guaranteed messaging components).

You may also use a separate component diagram, showing which class belongs to which component (remember not to build uber-diagrams, but instead aim for simplicity and showing only the relevant facets of the design)

This was a generic advice, but the answer you need is very context-specific. I can get more concrete if you can describe in more detail what are the classes in question, what are the projects (how do you delineate between them) and the overall architecture of the system.